# Random string generation in Java

Tags: java, performance, strings, random

Can random string generation be faster in Java?

Here is my current code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FastestStringGeneration {

    private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    private static final char[] ch = ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.toCharArray();
    private static final java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom random = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public static void main(String[] java) {
        // warmup code
        String[] warmUp = new String[10000];
        for (int j=0; j<10000; j++){
           warmUp[j] = getAlphaNumeric(1024);
        }
        // real code begins
        int numIterations = 1000000;
        String[] randomStrings = new String[numIterations];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0; i<numIterations; i++){
            randomStrings[i] = getAlphaNumeric(1024);
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
        System.out.println(randomStrings.length);
    }

    public static String getAlphaNumeric(int len) {
        char[] c = new char[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            c[i] = ch[random.nextInt(ch.length)];
        }
        return new String(c);
    }
}
```

The total time it takes to generate 1 million random strings is about ~ 5.9 seconds. Can it be faster?

I was using `java.util.Random` but when I changed to `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom` according to comments below I got the most performance improvement!

Comment: I was trying in other languages and was able to accomplish in ~5 seconds.

Comment: I have this code in one of my application and that is where it spends the most time and yeah the faster implementation I found on other languages doesn't seem to use Random everytime instead some crazy bit shifting logic so I am wondering if anyone here could possibly come up with a solution

Comment: For sure you have a big overhead due to the initial size of your array that's is 10 (as default). I suggest to initialize it with new ArrayList<>(numIterations). More, you can avoid List<> and use String[]. This will cut overhead about list managment before alghorytm that can use bitwise operations to be faster.

Comment: @MrPk Changed according to your suggestion didn't help much. maybe half a second gain.

Comment: you're not accounting for JVM warmup. the JVM needs a few hundred iterations to get the codepaths you're using to their full speed.

Comment: @Vogel612 Changed according to your suggestion..it barely helped anything.

Comment: Performance are all about machine, memory, type of JVM, bit of Java and so on (so it's 15 sec on your machine with your conditions, not an absolute timing). However you have to avoid to make "new String", String.valueOf(c)  it's better. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string

Comment: First thing that jumps at me is that you create a new `Random` for each String you generate. Try creating a `Random` once and reusing it.

Comment: I've implemented the two last suggestions in [this ideone](https://ideone.com/FGzS7F) (I've had to decrease the number of iterations in order to avoid running into the execution timeout) and while they show definite improvment I'm not sure they're as substantial as OP would hope for. Still, all tips taken into account seem to decrease the execution time from ~15s to ~11s

Comment: @PeterTaylor I had a typo. It should now.

Comment: @Aaron I ran it multiple times from commandline instead of IDE this time in my computer. it went from ~15s to ~13.5

Comment: @mtj  changed according to your suggestion now it is ~12.7 seconds.

Comment: I am not seeing how I can get down to ~5 seconds without changing the usage of Random.

Comment: use `private static java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();` instead of `java.util.Random`. The `java.util.Random` uses locks to be thread-safe, it slows down execution.

Comment: @MrPk I tried String.Valueof in this case it worsened the perfomance went down to ~28 seconds so I put it back to `new String(s)`. Regarding machine I am using the same machine to run the other prgram which gives ~5s except the program itself  is written in another language.

Comment: @user158037 I think what you suggested made a significant difference. Now it is ~6.7 seconds

Comment: I just commented out the warmup and ran through the command line. Its actually got faster a bit. it's ~5.8 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! that helps a lot. I ran it with Java 11 as well now it outperforms even my other program in Golang! its  ~4.7 seconds with Java 11

Comment: Hey @MrPk how come you didn't put this in an answer? It seems like as it stands your comments have brough the most performance improvement...

Comment: @Vogel612 is that supposed to be sarcastic? coz  user158037 feedback got me the most performance improvement and everyone else's comments were extremely useful so I thank everyone who commented here!

Comment: Welp. No. I thought that was you. Ehm. They should write an answer as well then 

Comment: I tried to - not sure if this is 'allowed' - parallelize the whole thing. It seemed to be faster, but it also seemed, the ThreadLocalRandom.current() spawned with the same seed, so it actually generated half of the wanted strings with two threads (but that's solvable I guess). There's also SplittableRandom to consider. With 10 threads I'm done in 2s, instead of ~7.5s of the current solution on my machine. Since the solution didn't work and I think multithreading is out of scope, I'm not posting it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is always identical you can save 1000000 calls to new().

Because `new String(char[])` uses `Arrays.copyOf()`, you don't need a new char[] in every loop.

```
private static int ourlen = 1024;
private static char[] chars = new char[ourlen];

public static String getAlphaNumeric() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ourlen; i++) {
        chars[i] = ch[random.nextInt(ch.length)];
    }
    return new String(c);
}
```

Comment: True. 300ms gain! Tells me Java object creation is awesome!